# What are the main concepts in the laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm starting to use Laravel 5.1, I got knowledge in php, js, angular, express, node, apache, mysql, sqlserver, and some other things.

In Angular I like that everything is built as singletons, so that the main concepts are: modules, controllers, services, factories, directives, routes, views, scopes, etc...

I'd like to know what concepts do I need to understand when building an app under laravel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically all you need to know is very well documented at [the official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1), Taylor Otwell made a huge effort doing the documentation to make the framwork more comprenhensible.

The basic concepts are:

- [Routing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing)
- [Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers)
- [Views](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views)
- [Blade templating](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)
- [Requests](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests) and [Responses](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses)
- Models & [Migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations)

After that keep an eye to in the [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware) concept, also there's a plenty of built-in services as: Auth, Pagination, Encryption, etc... check them out.

Something you'll love is [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent), it simplifies the interaction with the database.

Laravel community has their own site and that is [laracasts](http://laracasts.com) you could get help there too.

Answer (score 7):

One of the most important features of Laravel is the [Service Container](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container) (you'll hear about it also as the IoC Container) and the way it's used to register [Services](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers), provide Dependency Injection, and be a Registry for your application.

[Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) are one of my favorite feature of laravel: they are like filters executing before and after the requests, in which you can 'prepare' some data to be handled in the request or 'fix up' something after the request has been processed

Another peculiar feature are the [Facades](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades): (non to be confused with the homonym design pattern ) you'll see them everywhere, and you'll learn how they provide easy access to the service container keeping your code succint,readable and testable in the same time